# Octave: how to implement outer product for arbitrary functions and arbitrary number of arguments?

Tags: octave, outer-join

I now that in Mathematica you can use the general [outer product](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Outer.html) acting on a given function `f` and some lists `l1`, `l2`,`l3`,..., `ln`, such that the output `out` is a `n`-D-array/list with elements `out(i1,i2,...,in) = f(l1(i1),l2(i2),...,ln(in))`. The function can do whatever you want.

**How do you do the same in Octave/Matlab? Can you point me to the exisiting function and how to use it?**

I am aware of `arrayfun`, `cellfun` and `bsxfun`, but may be I dont fully understand how to use them.

My attempt until now is the following

```
%% outer product for anonymous function returning a cell
function out = outerf2(f,c1,c2)
  l1 = length(c1);
  l2 = length(c2);
  out = {};
  for i = 1:l1 for j = 1:l2
    out{i,j} = f(c1{i},c2{j});
  endfor endfor
endfunction
function out = outerf3(f,c1,c2,c3)
  l1 = length(c1);
  l2 = length(c2);
  l3 = length(c3);
  out = {};
  for i = 1:l1 for j = 1:l2 for k = 1:l3
    out{i,j,k} = f(c1{i},c2{j},c3{k});
  endfor endfor endfor
endfunction
```

The function `outerf2` accepts any function handle or anonymous function and evaluates it for all combinations of the elements of the cells `c1` and `c2`. The function `outerf3` does the same but for 3 cells.

Test 1 (see code below): anonymous function with matrix product.

Each of the elements of the output cell `temp1` is a 3x5 matrix (the result of the corresponding matrix product).

Test 2 (see code below): anonymous function using the tensor product

Each of the elements of the output cell `temp2` is a 4-D-array with dimensions [3,4,4,5] (the results of the corresponding tensor product and scalar multiplication of the element of `c3`). The Frobenius norm (square root of the sum of the squares of all elements of the array) is just used to check that the results are the same, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50679149/how-to-implement-tensor-product-for-arbitrary-order-tensors-in-octave), if you want to know the definitions, but the specific functions are not important.

```
%% Generate example cells
c1 = cellfun(@(i) rand(3,4),{1,2,3,4},"UniformOutput",false);
c2 = cellfun(@(i) rand(4,5),{1,2,3},"UniformOutput",false);
c3 = cellfun(@(i) rand(),{1,2,3,4,5,6},"UniformOutput",false);

%% Test 1
temp1 = outerf2(@(a1,a2) a1*a2,c1,c2);
size(temp1)
norm(temp1{2,3}-c1{2}*c2{3})

%% Test 2
% Tensor product
function out = tp(a,b)
  da = size(a);
  db = size(b);
  out = reshape(a(:)*(b(:)'),[da,db]);
endfunction
% Frobenius norm
function out = normf(a)
  out = sqrt(sum(a(:).*a(:)));
endfunction

temp2 = outerf3(@(a1,a2,a3) tp(a1,a2)*a3,c1,c2,c3);
size(temp2)
size(temp2{2,3,5})
normf(temp2{2,3,5}-tp(c1{2},c2{3})*c3{5})
```

Comment: `bsxfun` is the function that does this, but only for two arguments, and cell arrays are not accepted (in MATLAB at least, the [Octave documentation for this function](https://octave.sourceforge.io/octave/function/bsxfun.html) does not say what input types are allowed. It seems to me that your functions are the way to go.

Comment: Hmmm that is a bummer. Still thank you!

Comment: why do you use cell arrays if a matrix would do?

Comment: @Andy I dont understand what you mean. Can you give an example?